# Angular2 Async Validator not Pending

Tags: validation, angular2-forms

I'm following an online course in Angular2 and during a lesson that I was coding along with, I came across an error, but cannot figure out where I went wrong.

I tried to look at similar question around the web but couldn't find any valid solution. The closest I came was this answer, [angular2 async form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452392/angular2-async-form-validation), but either the suggestions were irrelevant or it didn't work.

Here is my code:

**Component**

```
export class SignUpFormComponent {
   form: ControlGroup;

constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
    this.form = fb.group({
        username: ['', Validators.compose([
            Validators.required, 
            UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace
        ]), UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}

signup(){
    console.log(this.form.value);
}
}
```

**Validators**

```
export class UsernameValidators{
static shouldBeUnique(control: Control){
    console.log("taken");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(control.value == "example")
                resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
            else
                resolve(null);
        }, 1000);
    });
}
static cannotContainSpace(control: Control){
    if(control.value.indexOf(" ") >= 0){
        return { cannotContainSpace: true };
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**Relevant parts of the form**

```
    <input 
        ngControl="username"
        id="username" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control"
        #username="ngForm">

    <div *ngIf="username.control.pending">Checking for uniqueness...</div>

   <div 
        *ngIf="username.errors.shouldBeUnique"
        class="alert alert-danger">
        Username is already taken.
    </div>
```

When I run a server locally and start typing into the form the div with the pending message does not appear, and if I type "example" into the input field the error message does not pop up. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: For one of many things that may be wrong, I think you input tag gas some error, it should look more like `<input 
        ngControl="username"
        id="username" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control">`

Comment: I don't believe there is any problem with the input tag. There are other divs that do properly show up when there is an error, e.g. one div with `*ngIf="username.errors.required"`, which works properly on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had to change the **tsconfig.json** file from `"target" : "es5"` to `"target" : "es6"`, I ran `npm install` in the terminal again, then ran `npm start`, which fixed the problem.